# Is there a second browser I can install on PClinuxOS Gnome?

Tags: browser, gnome, pclinuxos

I can't seem to find an alternative browser to the default browser "Firefox"  that will install on PClinuxOS 10.12 with Gnome desktop.

Does anyone know of a browser that will install on PClinuxOS Gnome, besides Firefox, or a way of installing let's say Chrome on this Distro?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://www.pclinuxos.com/?p=361) (no date available) Chrome is available for your distribution via the Synaptic Package Manager under the name chromium-browser.

Is the package manager available on your system?

Comment: Again thanks, I can't seem to go further at that link however It did indirectly lead me to an Opera browser that claims to work on PClinuxOS. I am inexperienced with this PClinuxOS so it may take some time to give results.   Cheers, Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely install the open source version of Chrome on the computer. Seeing that PClinuxOS uses the `apt` package manager, you can run the following command to install the open source Chromium browser.

`sudo apt-get install -y chromium-browser`

Comment: I'm giving myself a crash course in the terminal...I'll let you know how it went. Thanks, Dan.